# Angular and html - Failed to load resource

Tags: angularjs

I have a page that use `AngularJS` to display data and base on the user choice it display images.

The site works but in the console I have this issue:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://mysite.app/images/places/undefined
```

This is the html:

```
<img width="100%" height="100%" ng-src="@{{ selectedEvent.place.image | addFullPathToImage }}" alt="@{{ selectedEvent.place.name }}">
```

and this is the angular code:

```
app.filter('addFullPathToImage', function () {
    return function (text) {
        return mysite.paths.placesPath + "/" + text;
    }
});
```

The image works, how can I remove the console error?

Comment: it states that your `selectedEvent.place.image` is `undefined`. Can you check that it indeed contains the image name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently `selectedEvent.place.image` is first resolved to undefined on a first digest cycle, which gives you the 404, and later its actual value is set and another digest cycle displays the image.

You could go through your code to understand why is this done in 2 different cycles. Are you using an async operation, such a server call, before setting `selectedEvent.place.image`?

A quick work around would be to only put the image in the HTML once its value has been set in the scope. To do that you just have to add a `ng-if` like this:

```
<img
  ng-if  = "selectedEvent.place.image"
  width  = "100%"
  height = "100%"
  ng-src = "@{{ selectedEvent.place.image | addFullPathToImage }}"
  alt    = "@{{ selectedEvent.place.name }}"
>
```

PS: `width` and `height` attribute are quite obsolete, you should try to use a `style` attribute or a separate CSS instead.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I have added the `ng-if` and it works!